# How do I verify the port numbers on SQL Server Management Studio?

Tags: java, eclipse, numbers, port

I am running a project in Eclipse that uses JDBC drivers. However, every time I run it I get the following error:

The TCP/IP connection to the host localhost, port 1433 has failed. Error: "Connection refused: connect. Verify the connection properties. Make sure that an instance of SQL Server is running on the host and accepting TCP/IP connections at the port. Make sure that TCP connections to the port are not blocked by a firewall.".

I am sure that the SQL Server Management Studio is using the 1433 port as well. But I want to verify it. Can someone tell me where do I go to check? I've been playing around with SQL Server for the past one hour and I can't find the slightest clue as to where it is.

Thanks in advanced.

Comment: do u mind giving us some codes?

Answer (score 1):

Load up SQL Server configuration manager from start menu and check the network config. as per screenshot: http://tinypic.com/r/2hcgfgg/5

Comment: Worth noting that TCP/IP isn't enabled by default, in my experience. If it's a new installation of SQL Server they'll need to enable it and set the port, then restart the service (still using Configuration Manager).

Comment: Weird. I've always found it 'just works' and never needed to enable TCP after an install.

Answer (score 0):

Go to start > Programs > Microsoft SQL Server > Configuration Tools > **SQL Server Configuration Manager**

Expand SQL Native Client 10.0 Configuration. Click Client Protocols. Make sure TCP/IP is enabled. Then double click TCP/IP. The port should be listed under Default Port.

I use the telnet trick to test if I can connect to a port and make sure it's not something else blocking my connection. Open a command prompt from the client and type: `telnet hostname 1433`

If you get a blank black screen you've connected successfully on port 1433. If you get a connection error then you know the port is blocked somewhere.